# C# - repeat action from private void

Tags: c#

I'm a real beginner on c# and everything. But I was trying to make my first program when I got this problem. I've done the "private void closeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)" Wich says when click the custom close button it will show a confirm message.

But I want that one of the items on the menu strip named 'Exit', do the same thing as on that "private void closeButton_Click".

It's a short code, I could write a new message box and everything but it's got to be a way to simply repeat a code.

Here is the code

```
private void closeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to exit?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
            {
                //Close 'dialog'
            }
        }


private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            closeButton_Click = true;
        }
```

Comment: What's wrong with `closeButton_Click(null, null);` in the `exitToolStripMenuItem_Click` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using closeButton_Click as a boolean variable (setting it to true), but it is a method.

You can just call the method.

```
private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    closeButton_Click(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: While this might technically work. It's redundant and not very clean. You should be pointing the click event of both buttons to the same handler (see my answer for detail).

Comment: @Collin That's probably how I would do it too. This was just easier to explain since he's a self-professed beginner. :) Any performance difference of having one extra method on the stack is certainly not noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

The way this is done it .NET is through event handler delegates. In the case of different buttons, it's probably on their "Click" event. The setup looks like this:

```
protected void CloseHandler(object sender, EventArgs e){ /*code goes here*/ }

//two buttons, referencing the same handler.
firstButton.Click += CloseHandler;
secondButton.Click += CloseHandler;
```